# Creating external table to point to ORC data stored in Azure blob

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have ORC data files in Azure blob , I want to read this data from an ADX cluster by creating an external table. But it appears that we can't specify `orc` as `dataformat` while creating an external table. It seems to be only accepting TSV,CSV,JSON,PARQUET. Is there any workaround for this?

UPDATE:

As you can see in the below screenshot Kusto is not showing ORC as one of the options when I am trying to create an external table. Now I intend to use this external table for reading (querying) external data , not really export -- but I guess Kusto won't know my intention.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're referring to the following statement from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#format) on external tables:

```
Using external table for export scenario is limited to the following formats: CSV, TSV, JSON and Parquet
```

The statement says about scenario, when you export data from ADX to external storage. For "read" scenario, all data formats mentioned on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats) are supported.

Comment: But Kusto is not even showing orc as one of the available formats even for creation of external table , now what I intend to use it for (either export or querying) is another thing , but how will Kusto know that anyways. Added update in the original post about this with a screenshot.

Comment: It's probably just missing from IntelliSense. Please just try to write orc manually.